# On using $hash_array[$(global_alias)]

Tags: shell-script, zsh, alias

Identical code works on one system, fails on another:

```
% zsh --version
zsh 5.0.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
% typeset -A frobozz
% alias -g foo='echo xyz'
% frobozz[$(foo)]=9
% echo ${(kv)frobozz}
xyz 9
```

```
% zsh --version
zsh 5.1 (i386-unknown-netbsdelf6.1)
% typeset -A frobozz
% alias -g foo='echo xyz'
% frobozz[$(foo)]=9
zsh: not an identifier: frobozz[$(fooech9
```

I'd like to know how to get this to work on both systems.

It would also be nice to understand what on earth is going on in the failing case.

And as always, any advice on how to debug `zsh` scripts is always appreciated.  (I find `zsh` scripts essentially undebuggable...  The example above is an all-too-typical illustration of this.)

Comment: Reproduced on zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu). Looks like a plain old-fashioned bug to me. Some error in a string length computation.

Comment: @Gilles: thanks.  I just sent a bug report to the zsh-workers list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug (regression).

- Reported (by you, thanks) in https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2015/msg03017.html
- Fixed in https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2015/msg03042.html ([commit](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/ca0cb170119b3cef4ccdfc743b6c225e9e6eed53/))
- Released in version 5.2 in December 2015
- Introduced in [this commit](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/c0d01a6fe0c67911650730cf13a2b9a0db16e59b/) from January 2015 (according to `git bisect`) so that bug was affecting versions 5.0.8 (June 2015), 5.1 and 5.1.1 .